# Ruby True/False Array

Tags: arrays, ruby

The attached code needs to be able to check if the inputed number is in the array and then run if true and if false a message returned.

```
accounts = [5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 8451277, 1302850, 8080152, 4562555, 5552012, 5050552, 7825877, 1250255,
       1005231, 6545231, 3852085, 7576651, 7881200, 4581002,]
puts "What is your account number?"
my_account = gets.to_i
for v in (my_account)
  if v ==(my_account) 
    puts "Welcome to your account"
  end
end
```

Comment: undefined method `each' for 5658845:Integer Error that keeps occuring

Comment: You'll want to confirm `gets.chomp` is the string representation of a natural number (non-negative integer). If, for example, `gets => "cat\n"`, `my_account = gets.to_i #=> 0` and you will merrily check to see if `accounts` contains a zero. See [String#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-to_i) to understand why `"cats\n".to_i #=> 0`. You can check that with a regular expression. If it should be a natural number, `gets.chomp =~ /\D/` is `true` if `gets.chomp` contains a character other than a digit, so you want `!(gets.chomp =~ /\D/)` or `gets.chomp !~ /\D/)`.

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong

```
for v in (my_account)
```

it should be

```
for v in accounts
```

You want to go through the numbers in `accounts` array, not `my_account`, that's just a single number

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
accounts = [5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 8451277, 1302850, 8080152, 4562555, 5552012, 5050552, 7825877, 1250255,
       1005231, 6545231, 3852085, 7576651, 7881200, 4581002,]
puts "What is your account number?"
my_account = gets.to_i
if accounts.include?(my_account)
  puts "Welcome to your account"
else
  # do whatever you need to do
end
```

Comment: Why do you need a comma after the last element of the array?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Array#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-include-3F)

```
accounts = [5658845, 4520125, 7895122, 8777541, 8451277, 1302850, 8080152, 4562555, 5552012, 5050552, 7825877, 1250255, 1005231, 6545231, 3852085, 7576651, 7881200, 581002]
puts 'What is your account number?'
my_account = gets.to_i

if accounts.include?  my_account
  puts 'Welcome to your account'
else
  puts 'It is not you account'
end
```

Using `for` with `puts` you will enumerate all items in your array.

For example:

```
accounts = [1, 2, 3]
puts "What is your account number?"
my_account = gets.to_i

for v in accounts
  if v == my_account
    puts "Welcome to your account #{v}"
  else
    puts "#{v} is not your account"
  end
end

# What is your account number?
# 2
# 1 is not your account
# Welcome to your account 2
# 3 is not your account
```

Comment: Well, in the worst case `Array#include?` would also walk through the whole array :)